# Mongoengine check if object exists without fetching the object

Tags: mongoengine

On Django we can use the `QuerySet.exists()` to check if an object exists in the DB in the most efficient way, without actually fetching the record.

Is there an equivalent function on Mongoengine?

Answer (score 2):

According to official documentation, here is [solution](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.with_id) how to make this if you have object id.Its the best solution for your case, that i have seen in mongoengine documentation.It works as below:

```
# Returns None or Object if it exists
result = Collection.objects.with_id(object_id=*your object id*)
if result is None:
  # raise error
else:
  # make some actions with this object
```

Is this is what are you looking for?

Comment: This actually fetches the record, which is what you _don't_ want.

From docs: "Retrieve the object matching the id provided."

Right?

Comment: I faced the same problem and ended up using count() on mongoengine objects
From mongoengine docs,
You could technically use len(User.objects) to get the same result, but it would be significantly slower than count(). When you execute a server-side count query, you let MongoDB do the heavy lifting and you receive a single integer over the wire. Meanwhile, len() retrieves all the results, places them in a local cache, and finally counts them. If we compare the performance of the two operations, len() is much slower than count().

Comment: @zaffer, that way could be very expensive. And calling len(User.objects) is a good way to kill efficiency of any database/application, cause you are loading object to application memory(even if it's only ID's).